# iOS : Is there a way to replace string that mostly like same?

Tags: ios, string, replace, format

I have some html code that I want to replace at some point.

Such as

```
NSString *stringSHOW = @"width="353" height="500" width="131" height="204" width="777" width="369" width="888"/>";
```

Something like this. But I want to replace all `[ width="any" to width="300" ]`.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the docs for [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the `NSString` methods which take regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *newStringShow = [stringShow stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"any"withString:@"300"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *)updateString:(NSString *)inputString withString:(NSString *)stringToReplace {

    NSArray *components = [inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSMutableArray *mutableComponents = [[components mutableCopy] autorelease];

    for (NSString *componentString in components) {

        NSMutableString *mutableString = [[componentString mutableCopy] autorelease];
        NSRange replaceRangeFirstOccurenceStart = [mutableString rangeOfString:@"width=\""];
        if (replaceRangeFirstOccurenceStart.location == NSNotFound) {
            NSLog(@"String not found in component");
        }
        NSMutableString *replaceString = [NSMutableString string];
        for (int i = 0; i < replaceRangeFirstOccurenceStart.length; i ++) {
            [replaceString appendString:@"_"];
        }
        NSMutableString *modifiedString = [mutableString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:replaceRangeFirstOccurenceStart withString:replaceString];
        NSRange replaceRangeEnd = [modifiedString rangeOfString:@"\""];
        NSRange rangeToChange = NSMakeRange(replaceRangeFirstOccurenceStart.length - 1, replaceRangeEnd.location + replaceRangeEnd.length - replaceRangeFirstOccurenceStart.length + 1);        
        NSString *updatedString = [mutableString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:rangeToChange withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"", stringToReplace]];
        [mutableComponents replaceObjectAtIndex:[components indexOfObject:componentString] withObject:updatedString];
    }
    return [mutableComponents componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
}

NSString *stringShow = @"width=\"355\" width=\"200\"";
[self updateString:stringShow withString:@"34501"];
```

You can also send as params the delimiters strings, in your case @"width=\"" and @"\"" to make this method entirely abstract and to be able to replace anything you pass it.